# If your network is slow and you keep trying to upvote one of your answers just continuously clicking on it again and again your answer get upvoted

Tags: discussion, support, bug, voting, up-votes

[image]

So I have discovered a bug or hack whatever you may call it. So today morning my network was bit slow ($<5$ MBPS). So I answered a question and I wanted to answer more question but slow network made it load too much. So the answer which I had posted I was continuously upvoting it and receiving message You can't upvote your post but suddenly after $25$ to $30$ clicks my post got upvoted like you can see in the image. I waited for $2$ minutes and didn't receive any message. Then I again clicked on upvote button to remove the upvote and again clicked on upvote button but now it wasn't upvoted and I received message You can't upvote your post. So is it a feature of site which I don't guess so. So I would like to ask is it some kind of bug. Currently my internet speed is good ($>40$ MBPS).

Comment: I’ve done this before to and noticed that it was only client side. When I reloaded the page the upvote was gone, have you tried this in your case?

Comment: Sorry when it was showing my upvote I didn't refresh the page after 2 minutes I removed the upvote and tried to upvote it again at that time it didn't upvote. But imo it was really a upvote and not just from client side @user400188

Comment: I would be very surprised if it was not just a visual bug on the client side (in particular you do not seem to have any increase in rep)

Comment: @CalvinKhor ya although there was a upvote there was no increase in reputation

Comment: Client side: meaning you saw the upvote, but it did not "take" ON SITE.  No one is doubting you saw it, but "client side" means it appeared on your screen, but it was not valid, and had you refreshed, you would no longer see it.

Comment: @amWhy okay I think this was only the case

Comment: @amWhy type it as a answer and I will accept it